# Adding value to int variable each run of the loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, int

sorry if this is a repeat question or sounds pretty stupid, but I'm really new to c# and looked throughout the forum and couldn't find anything that I could actually understand.

So I'm trying to write a simple program where the user tries to guess a number between 1 and 25. Everything works except that each run of the loop instead of updating the score from the last run of the loop, like 0+1=1, 1+1=2, 2+1=3, each time it adds 1 to 0. Here is my code. How do I fix this? Thank you!

```
int score = 0;
int add = 1;

while (add == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess A Number Between 1 and 25");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input == "18")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Did It!");
        Console.WriteLine("Not Bad! Your Score was " + score + add);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try Again. Score: " + score + add);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to actually add `add` to `score`. Try something like this:

```
int score = 0;
int add = 1;

while (add == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Guess A Number Between 1 and 25");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    score += add; // add `add` to `score`. This is the same as `score = score + add;`

    if (input == "18")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Did It!");
        Console.WriteLine("Not Bad! Your Score was " + score);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try Again. Score: " + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: source += add is the same thing as source = source + add, if you are new to C# that might be confusing